# How do I disable express logs in my node.js CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, express

I am new to node.js and I am trying to move away from using console.log for debugging everything. I am trying to use

```
debug("test message")
```

instead of console.log for everything.

I installed the debug npm package, and it instructed me to:

```
set DEBUG=* node server.js
```

But, with my express package, I get the following: 
[image: code picture]

The app message in blue is the only relevant message to me since I am trying to use that instead of console.log. How can I get rid of these express logs? Do you think at some point they would be important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use it like

`dbg=debug('myserver:app')`

and output messages with

`dbg('A new message')`

also to output only those messages that you want

`set DEBUG=myserver:app node server.js`

you can also exclude with `-` or include like `myserver:app,express:*`

with DEBUG environmental variable you can specify what to output or no. more information https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug check the wildcards and examples

Comment: for the dbg part, is myserver equal to my server.js file and app = my app variable?

Comment: no it can be anything but think it as an namespace, if your npm package is named `knockoutmap` you can use `knockoutmap:application` or add another debug `knockoutmap:critical` set DEBUG to whatever you want it to output.

Comment: Even though it does work for me now, I'm still a little confused. I have 'var debug = require('debug')('app')' and 'debug('test') which works now after I did the 'set DEBUG=app' command. Is the ('app') part referring to 'var app = express();' or is it just a namespace?

Comment: it's a plain namespace, it can't process variables if you look at `require('debug')('test')` it immediately requires and creates a debug instance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command which worked for me is:

```
set DEBUG=*,-express:*  node server.js
```

this will enable all messages, then exclude everything starting with `express:`